# How can I Retrieve Wrong Transfer of Erc20 tokens

Tags: transactions, tokens, erc-20, addresses, etherscan

I mistakenly Transfer an ERC20 token to a scammer Like(I created the Token) then I saw the Write function on etherscan.io. Is it possible to transfer it back to my wallet or not and if it is possible how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to transfer a token using the `transfer()` function unless you own the private key of the EOA that holds the tokens.